# Splitting a string based on a list

Tags: python

I have a list like this:
`destinations = ['one', 'two', 'three']`.  I have an input string that I am splitting like this: `one, two, three = re.split(r'\t', line)`.  What I'd like to do is have the split operation fill a dictionary, with the `destinations` entries being the keys of the dictionary, and the fields from the line being the values.  Is this possible with python?

Comment: Disregard my comment; I missed that you are using `re.split()` rather than `str.split()`. Which does raise the question why you are not using `line.split('\t')` here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up `destinations` and the output of `re.split()` into key-value pairs, then pass that to [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

```
dictionary = dict(zip(destinations, re.split(r'\t', line)))
```

I suspect you are trying to read tab-separated CSV data; try not to reinvent the wheel and use the [`csv.DictReader()` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) instead. It'll even read the fieldnames from the first row of the file, if so required.